# Cannot call scalar function and function return wrong value

Tags: sql-server, function, scalar, sql-server-2017

### I create scalar function to count row from pass variable as below.

```
    CREATE procedure [dbo].[CARFCN](@NBLC Varchar) returns int
as 
Begin
    Declare @CDLF INT
    set @CDLF = (select count([*Downlink EARFCN]) from EutranInterNFreq$ 
     where NodeB_Locell = @NBLC)
return @CDLF
End
```

---

question 1.  This function cannot use in select. How to use?

```
select cell.[*eNodeB Name],cell.[*eNodeB ID],cell.[*Cell Name], cell. 
[Downlink EARFCN], Cell.[Nodeb Locell], 
[dbo].CARFCN(CELL.[*eNodeB Name]) as NUM
from ais.dbo.cell$ CELL
LEFT JOIN ais.dbo.EutranInterNFreq$ InterN
on cell.[Nodeb Locell]= interN.[NodeB_Locell];
```

error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'dbo'.   What I am wrong?

Question 2
Then I try to minimize problem I create sql to call as below.

```
select dbo.CARFCn('ABCRM_101') as numb;  This return value 0 ????
```

but if i call query as below answer is 2

```
select count([*Downlink EARFCN]) from EutranInterNFreq$ where NodeB_Locell = 
'ABCRM_101');
```

Why is that and how to fix?

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: sql server 2017 developer edition

Comment: No, you did not create "scalar function".You created a stored procedure.  Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) again and try converting your code to a function.